ISO Azure Feature Equivalent: Role trust policy for session tags in AWS
I'm looking for an Azure equivalent of custom claim validation like AWS has in session tags?
{
    "Sid": "AllowPassSessionTagsAndTransitive",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:TagSession",
    "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/test-session-tags"},
    "Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
        "aws:RequestTag/Project": "*",
        "aws:RequestTag/CostCenter": "*"
    },
    "StringEquals": {
        "aws:RequestTag/Department": [
            "Engineering",
            "Marketing"
        ]
    },
    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
        "sts:TransitiveTagKeys": [
            "Project",
            "Department"
         ]
      }
   }
}

Context:
I have an OIDC token that contains custom claims
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "kid": "12345",
  "typ": "JWT"
}.
{
  "aud": "AUDIENCE_NAME"
  "iss": "SOME_ISSUER",
  ...
  "customClaim1": "foo",
  "customClaim2": "bar",
}

I've worked through Azure's Workload Identity Federation and Conditional Access documentation but nothing seems to fit the feature of checking that customClaim1 == "foo" before providing an Azure access token.
I want to add a trust policy in Azure that does similar validation like AWS does with session tags. Which grants access to OIDC tokens if the custom claims / session tags match specific conditions. Google also has a similar feature.

Could you please include more details like what code you tried by editing your question?

Azure does not have a direct equivalent to AWS's session tags feature for custom claim validation in OIDC tokens.

As I said in comment section, Azure does not have a direct equivalent to AWS's session tags, but you can achieve similar functionality using Azure AD Conditional Access and custom claims in tokens.  Azure AD Conditional Access policies can be configured to enforce access based on custom claims in tokens. You can use Azure AD B2C to create custom policies that validate specific claims in the token before granting access.
Example to configure a custom policy in Azure AD B2C to validate a custom claim-
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertCustomClaimEqualsFoo" TransformationMethod="AssertStringClaimIsEqualToValue">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="customClaim1" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="string" Value="foo" />
  </InputParameters>
</ClaimsTransformation>

Also checkout- Use custom attributes for Attribute-Based Access Control (ABAC) with Microsoft Entra ID and AWS IAM Identity Center | Microsoft Workloads on AWS (amazon.com)
